# Copy and paste text keep bold only

Tags: c#, ms-word, format, office-interop

I have a word document that has all kind of craziness (about the format, not content) in it.

The only way to remove the craziness is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to a Notepad file. But with just the raw text, it really hard to understand the document, thus I want to keep the **bold format** (and text size as optional) in the word document.

Is there anyway I can use C# to copy the text in the word document with bold format?

Comment: Is this an [Office Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/office-interop/info) thing?

Comment: @Uwe Keim : Yes, It is  an Office Interop thing

Answer (score 1):

This copies all content to the end of the document, applies bold font by comparing the original text with the new text and removes the original text.

```
private static void KeepOnlyBoldFormatting(Word.Document document)
{
    var undoRecord = document.Application.UndoRecord;

    try
    {
        document.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;

        undoRecord.StartCustomRecord("KeepOnlyBoldFormatting");

        var originalRange = document.Range();
        var originalEnd = originalRange.End - 1; //Skip last character (paragraph marker that cannot be removed)

        originalRange.InsertAfter(originalRange.Text.Substring(0, originalRange.Text.Length - 1));

        //Make sure the ranges refer to the right things
        originalRange.Start = 0;
        originalRange.End = originalEnd;
        var newRange = document.Range(originalEnd, originalEnd + originalEnd);

        for (int i = 1; i <= originalRange.Characters.Count; i++)
        {
            var origChar = originalRange.Characters[i];
            var newChar = newRange.Characters[i];

            if (origChar.Bold == -1)
                newChar.Bold = -1;

        }

        originalRange.Delete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        document.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
        undoRecord.EndCustomRecord();
    }

}
```

Comment: When the 

[originalEnd = 1660925]

, then the code [var newRange = document.Range(originalEnd, originalEnd + originalEnd);]

throws exception: "Value out of range"

Comment: Maybe originalEnd + originalEnd - 1? Perhaps I'm banking on an added line break that isn't alwyas there or something